# Ubuntu, nginx, RTMP, Twitch - Playing local videofiles randomly when offline + authentication?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, rtmp

I've rented myself a vServer, installed Ubunto, nginx and made a simple RTMP forwarding to Twitch according to this guide:

[How to set up your own private RTMP server using nginx](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/how-to-set-up-your-own-private-rtmp-server-using-nginx.50/)

The forwarding with the RMTP works fine, but I've got some things I want to do with it but I don't know how. Hopefully you can help me! :/

I made this basically so we can switch between streamers without the disconnect-/connect-gaps. Is there a possibility to play local video files from the server (maybe in random order) when not streaming until someone connects and again when he goes offline? If not, just a black screen or an image?

Is it possible to add authentication with individual Keys via the streaming software with keys I'm just generating and provide them to the streamers?

Thanks in advance!

Hopeful regards,
Tim

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no direct solution to your problem but I want basically the same behavior and therefore I tried to find out ways of how to accomplish it.

For both problems (authentication / stream redirection) I can only give you hints, no polished solutions.

For authentication you can use `on_connect` with a custom handler to handle authentication. The same works for `on_play` which would be "auth to watch". You can find more information on that [in the directive documentation](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/wiki/Directives#on_connect) and a [sample implementation on Helping Squad](http://www.helping-squad.com/nginx-rtmp-secure-your-nginx-server/).

With RTMP redirection you could accomplish to play local files and switch between different streams / applications. I haven't figured this part completely yet but [this article](http://nginx-rtmp.blogspot.de/2014/01/redirecting-streams-in-version-111.html) seems to give a good idea of how it could work. It uses the control module from the nginx rtmp module.